# Why did serial no. vanish from CrystalDiskInfo?

Tags: ssd, smart

I've been using CrystalDiskInfo to monitor my ssd and today noticed that in place of where a serial number used to be displayed, I now see "************" instead.  What might have caused this?  Does it have to do with total writes having just crossed 10 TB?  Is this a sign of impending failure?

[image: no serial no.]

Comment: Why are you not running the latest version (8.3.0)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, I just updated it, but nothing substantial changed in the display (I would've been surprised if it had).

Answer (score 1):

The serial number is probably hidden because of an app setting.

**Function** -> **Hide Serial Number**

See if this is checked. It exists in x64 v8.11.1, at least.